# Enumerate subsets that intersect each subset in a fixed family

Tags: algorithms

Let $\Omega=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and let $A_i\subset \Omega$, $1\leq i\leq m$ be a fixed family of subsets of $\Omega$.

Let 
$$
\mathcal{A}:=\{B\subset \Omega: B\cap A_i \neq \varnothing \;\forall 1\leq i\leq m\}.
$$

Is there an efficient way to enumerate $\mathcal{A}$ in any order that is compatible with the cardinality partial order, i.e. find $B_j\in\mathcal{A}$, $1\leq j\leq L$ such that $|B_j|\leq |B_{j+1}|$ and $\mathcal{A}=\{B_1,...,B_L\}$?

Of course I can always just enumerate all subsets  of $\Omega$ in a way that respects the cardinality  order and check  for each subset whether it is in $\mathcal{A}$. However, this can be rather inefficient. For example, if $A_{i}=\{i\}$, $1\leq i\leq m=n$, then $\mathcal{A}=\{\Omega\}$  but obtaining that single element of $\mathcal{A}$ would take $2^n$ steps.

PS: 
The specific order of the $B_j$ is not important, but it would be nice if the order did not depend on $\mathcal{A}$. In other words, I want to apply the same algorithm to another scenario with $\tilde{A}_i$ such that the corresponding $\tilde{B}_j$ are ordered in the same way. However, this is not a strict requirement, I'm sure I will find a workaround.

Comment: In your definition of $\mathcal{A}$, I'm not understanding what you ask. Does $B$ have to be non empty? Or the $A_i$?

Comment: @GuillermoMosse sorry, fixed it, the intersection should be nonempty

Comment: I have many issues with how you define your "order", but shouldn't $\Omega$ always be the largest in the ordering ? Then you get $\{2,3\}_{++}=\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @N.Bach you're right, I stopped that listing one step too early (in my real application I'm interested in strict subsets only, but since I used $\Omega$ in the quickly made up worst case example it got confusing. I'll fix it) What issues do you have with the ordering?

Comment: Assuming I've understood properly, the first thing that bothers me is that your order relation isn't anti-symmetric. Say $n\ge 12$, as subsets you have $\{12\}\neq\{1,2\}$, but by your order $\{12\}=\{1,2\}$. Now say that both subsets belong to $\mathcal A$. Then $\{11\}_{++}$ has (at least) two candidates. Is one of them enough, is there an additional criteria to pick the "best" subset, or do you want all of them?

Comment: The other issue I have, is that this order depends on the base in which you write numbers. Say for some reason you switch to hexadecimal, then $\{12\}$ becomes `0xC`$=12$, but $\{1,2\}$ is `0x12`$=18$. Now you obtain $\{12\} < \{1,2\}$, which differs from what happens in base 10... I guess you only care about base 10, but it still weirds me out. Well the tl;dr is that if you want an efficient way to enumerate $\mathcal A$, my uneasiness about your order isn't relevant. If what you really need is to compute $A_{++}$, then those details are maybe relevant.

Comment: @N.Bach good point. I really just want an enumeration that respects the cardinality order. I was assuming the base used is equal to or larger than $n$ but of course that's all very confusing... I hope it's clear now. As per your suggestion I gave up on imposing a specific order

Comment: If $1,\ldots,n$ are always digits in the base, I can live with that. One more question, is it reasonable to use $O(nL)$ memory for your problem? Or do you have to compute the elements of $\mathcal A$ one by one?

Comment: @N.Bach I do use them one by one. Actually, my problem starts is a bit more involved than in the question. I start out with $m=1$ so $\mathcal{A}$ will be quite large and I certainly don't want all of it my memory. Instead, I do some computations with the first element of $\mathcal{A}$ and from those computations will likely get another condition. Thus, $m=2$ and the new $\mathcal{A}$  is already smaller than before, but again I only need one element of this new $\mathcal{A}$ and will likely get yet another condition out of it that makes the new new $\mathcal{A}$ even smaller etc.

Comment: @N.Bach this is why my question was first posed differently with more of a focus on computing the next element